# tkinter after() function won't call itself to create loop

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I am trying to make a clock inside of a tkinter program using start.  According to the docs the first after should call a function, then you should put the after function in the called function as well to make it run over and over.  However, when I do that, the first after will call my function just fine, and then the call to after that is in my function will tell me that the function is not defined.  I don't understand why this is happening or how to fix it.

First call to after is at the bottom, and it calls the updateTime() func.  It is in that function that it should call itself after a 1 sec delay, but gives the error.

Also, I am new to python and tkinter, so if this is the wrong way to go about this then let me know.  the after function just seemed like the best way to do this.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
#from relayControl import switchOnOff

#Pin numbers:
#Light:  2
#Fan:    3

class Main:

    def exit():
        quit()

    def lightSwitch():
        print("Light on")
        #switchOnOff(2)

    def fanSwitch():
        print("Fan on")
        #switchOnOff(3)

    def updateTime(timeLabel, root):
        timeLabel.config(text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%s", time.localtime()))
        root.after(100, updateTime(timeLabel, root))


    root = Tk()
    root.configure(background="black")
    root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

    # ***Time(center)***
    timeLabel = Label(root, text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%s", time.localtime()), bg="black", fg="red")
    timeLabel.grid(row=2, column=2)

    # ***Alarm(top left)***
    alarmLabel = Label(root, text="Alarm Time", bg="black", fg="red")
    alarmLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)

    # ***Exit(bottom right)
    exitButton = Button(root, text="Exit", bg="red", highlightbackground="red", command=exit)
    exitButton.grid(row=3, column=3)

    # ***Frequently used switches(top right)***
    buttonFrame = Frame(root, bg="black")
    buttonFrame.grid(row=1, column=3)

    lightSwitch = Button(buttonFrame, text="Light", bg="red", highlightbackground="red", command=lightSwitch)
    lightSwitch.pack()

    fanSwitch = Button(buttonFrame, text="Fan", bg="red", highlightbackground="red", command=fanSwitch)
    fanSwitch.pack()

    root.after(100, updateTime(timeLabel, root))
    root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leemorgan/projects/python/automatedHome/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Main:
  File "/home/leemorgan/projects/python/automatedHome/main.py", line 60, in Main
    root.after(100, updateTime(timeLabel, root))
  File "/home/leemorgan/projects/python/automatedHome/main.py", line 24, in updateTime
    root.after(100, updateTime(timeLabel, root))
NameError: global name 'updateTime' is not defined
```

Comment: Must be `self.updateTime`.

Comment: Ok, that seems to work but I get another issue.  I have to add self to the function parameters for this.  So what do I pass in for this parameter when I call it?  I pass in two parameters and but it takes 3 now.

Comment: You seem to be in the dark on how to create class methods. _Each_ class method must take `self` as the first parameter.

Comment: Ya, sorry.  Coming from languages like Java and C++ so this is strange to me.  From the examples I looked up it seems that they take self as the first parameter and you don't need to pass that in.  Well, I added self to all methods, got that.  However, it is still telling me that I have to pass in 3 parameters instead of two.

Comment: Actually, you have a bigger problem. When you pass a parameter to `root.after`, it must be a function name, not a function call.

Comment: You're also not passing the arguments to the the `after()` method correctly. Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) I found about it. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246709/tkinter-analog-clock-refreshing-how-does-after-function-work/30248967#30248967) of mine for an example of using it.

Comment: Yep, just figured it out.  First, it seems that a class is maybe not appropriate here.  Took that out first.  Then realized I was passing the arguments wrong so I fixed that.  Seems to be working now.  Thanks for the help.  Classes seem quite different in python from java, c++, c#.  I think modules are closer to classes in those languages.  Correct me if I am off base.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `lambda` command so try:

```
root.after (100, lambda timeLabel = timeLabel, root = root: Main.updateTime (timeLabel, root))
```

EDIT:
Using Brian Oakley's comment (a much better way of doing it):

```
root.after (100, Main.updateTime, timeLabel, root)
```

Comment: You can use `lambda`, but you don't need to. IMO it makes the code harder to read. You can pass arguments directly within `after`: `root.after(100, Main.updateTIme, timeLabel, root)`

Comment: Cool! I didn't realise that!